# Can I contribute device driver to opensource when datasheet is under NDA/confidential?

Tags: open-source-definition, nda

Let's consider a scenario where when working on embedded software, I had to obtain datasheet related to some chip from X manufacturer. This datasheet is not publicly available, but can be obtained under NDA or under specific terms of service.

Question related to NDA and opensource has been open for a very long time, for example https://lwn.net/Articles/203562/. But this article relates to ***drivers written under NDA*** and not ***drivers written based on datasheet that is under NDA***.

So, is it allowed to contribute driver to opensource when to write it confidential datasheet was needed? Or does it depend sorely on NDA/terms of use?

Comment: What is the difference between using the NDA-encumbered documentation and reverse-engineering the hardware and writing a driver based on that results?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question (interpretation of NDAs) is off-topic here. It should be asked in Law SE or somewhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, is it allowed to contribute driver to opensource when to write it confidential datasheet was needed? Or does it depend sorely on NDA/terms of use?

It depends almost entirely on the terms in the NDA, but I would expect that any properly drafted NDA contains a clause that forbids you to disclose the *information* that you receive under the NDA.

As the source code of the driver contains basically a subset of the information that is in the datasheet, if the NDA forbids disclosure of the information, that means that you are not allowed to distribute the source code. This is independent of what license you would want to attach to the driver.

Comment: This answer appears to generalize things, based on certain assumptions. These assumptions should be mentioned: (a) the specific part of the information used for the software is not available elsewhere, only in the NDA-protected datasheet; (b) the NDA itself is valid, reasonable and enforceable. There might be many situations (depending on jurisdictions), where these prerequisites are not fulfilled.

Comment: Point (a) is very often true, with how manufacturers of hardware work. Datasheets and many other materials are not available elsewhere. But point (b) is interesting, but testing that may involve getting into trouble.